# How do I hide a specific search extension from search?

Tags: 2010, search

Our client would like to hide .zip files from search. How do I go about doing this?

The two options I see are to log into central admin and manage the search application, then to go to 'File Types' and delete the zip file type. The other option is to create a new crawl rule and exclude http://somedomain/*.zip

Will either of those work, and if so, what's preferred? Also, if the 'File Types' section isn't what I'm supposed to use, what is the purpose of that section?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use the later option you list, a search exclusion rule.  Removing it from the File Types section will have the same impact, I just prefer to leave that with the default configuration and keep everything in exclusion rules.

Different strokes for different folks.

Comment: This worked, thanks. I didn't have time to test the file type removal only.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend removing .zip from the allowed file types in the search service application configuration. This is a closer fit to your requirement, and is what that facility was designed for.

If you rely on crawl rules you run the risk of unintentionally allowing the zip files through as you adjust the crawl rules in the future.

Having said that, both solutions will work.

Comment: Oh well, looks like I'll have to rely on the sympathy up-vote :-?

Comment: +1 for the good doctor.

Comment: Thanks - I didn't have time to test this on its own, so I went with what worked. I'll give you some more sympathy.

Comment: Yes.. poor doctor and his 3.5k rep. ;)